# Detecting collisions vertically

Tags: java, collision-detection

I'm working with a project in which I want to detect collisions with two drawn objects.

This is working fine when having objects that reach horizontally, but when they are going vertically it doesn't seem to work correctly.

The code I am using is:

```
p = playerBox
t = targetBox
if ((t.x>=p.x && t.x<=p.x+p.w) || (t.x+t.w>=p.x && t.x+t.w<=p.x+p.w)) {
    if ((t.y>=p.y && t.y<=p.y+p.h) || (t.y+t.h>=p.y && t.y+t.h<=p.y+p.h) {
        System.out.println("Player p collided with target t!");
    }
}
```

The drawn box I have looks like this:

```
g.fillRect(100, 200, 20, 100);
```

and what i have written is:

```
if ((100 >= X && 100 <= X + 20) || (100 + 20 >= X && 100 + 20 <= X + 20)) {
    if ((200 >= Y && 200 <= Y + 20) || (200 + 100 >= Y && 200 + 100 <= Y + 20)) {

        lblGameOver.setText("Game Over");//första muren lodrätt
        btnUp.setEnabled(false);
        btnDown.setEnabled(false);
        btnRight.setEnabled(false);
        btnLeft.setEnabled(false);

    }
}
```

It seems like it only detects my other rectangle at the coordinate (100, 300).

Any ideas about what might be the issue here?

Comment: Why don't you write a collidesWith method in the rectangle class? then it will be easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: Or, why not just keep track of hitboxes for your objects and then use `Rectangle.intersects()`?

Comment: java.awt.Polygon#contains(Point p) the source code of this class migth help. its part of JDK

Comment: Oh, didn't know about the rectangle class. Thanks for letting me know!